# Как изменить Content-Type в RabbitMQ (Spring JMS)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, rabbitmq, jms

Всем привет! Проблема в следующем:

У меня есть приложение, которое слушает определенную очередь в RabbitMQ. Когда в эту очередь поступает сообщение, то оно определенным образом обрабатывается. Проблема в том, что в эту очередь нельзя загружать обычные сообщения без заголовков и кодирования (например, в base64).

Если я помещу в очередь обычное сообщение (ниже есть пример), то в программе будет ошибка в виде `Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue' - trying to recover. Cause: invalid stream header: 304A2F52`.

Причем само сообщение он получает: есть метод `RMQMessage#fromMessage(byte[] b, List<String> trustedPackages) throws RMQJMSException` и если там поставить точку остановки, то видно, что в переменную `b` приходит именно то, что я отправлял.

[image: Пример обычного сообщения]

Опытным путём я выяснил, что его не устраивает вид, в котором приходит сообщение и понял, что вот такие сообщения программа разбирает правильно:

[image: Пример правильного сообщения]

И как следствие вывод приложения нормальный:

```
2021-10-15 16:10:12.286  INFO 14264 --- [enerContainer-1] .m.m.w.CustomMessageListener :  [x] Received <<< queue Привет
```

Вопрос в том, как можно перенастроить RabbitMQ Client, чтобы он мог принимать обычные текстовые сообщения, а не закодированные с кучей заголовков.

Зависимость я использую следующую:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.rabbitmq.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>rabbitmq-jms</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Назначение слушателей происходит следующим образом (код немного видоизменен и в реальности происходит динамическое создания очередей + назначение им слушателей, но в любом случае это делается через `JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar`):

```
public class JmsListenerConfiguration implements JmsListenerConfigurer {
    
    private final CustomMessageListener messageListener;
    
    @Override
    public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        final String queue = "queue";

        final SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();    
        endpoint.setId(queue);
        endpoint.setDestination(queue);
        endpoint.setMessageListener((message) -> messageListener.onMessage(message, queue));
        
        registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема не в самой очереди или настройке rabbitmq. У вас проблема в том, что ваше (?) приложение использует эту конкретную очередь для хранения JMS сообщений, т.е. сообщений для специфической задачи в специфическом формате.

Если вы туда отправляете сообщения в другом виде с другой целью, то ясно, что клиент, который читает из очереди и ожидает там увидеть JMS сообщение (а оно имеет особый формат и особые заголовки), их не понимает. Формат сообщения задается клиентом, т.е. библиотекой rabbitmq-jms, он строго определен и не настраивается. [Тут](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-jms-client/blob/main/src/main/java/com/rabbitmq/jms/client/RMQMessage.java#L1076) можно посмотреть, как тело сообщения формируется из `Message`.

Чтоб решить вашу проблему, нужно понимать зачем вам это. Если вы хотите посылать сообщения, чтоб их мог обрабатывать существующий JMS клиент, то никуда не денетесь - нужно посылать в формате, который поддерживает rabbitmq JMS клиент.

Если же вы хотите посылать сообщения другим клиентам, то не нужно использовать эту же очередь - нужно создать новую очередь, конкретно под вашу задачу, и самое главное - не добавлять в нее сообщения JMS, а использовать классы из `spring-rabbitmq`: `RabbitTemplate` для посылки и `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` для получения сообщений:

```
// посылка без подтверждения
RabbitTemplate someExchangeTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
someExchangeTemplate.setExchange("exchange-name");

byte[] myData = ...;
someExchangeTemplate.send(new Message(myData, new MessageProperties()));

// получение
container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
container.setMessageListener((Message m) -> {
   byte[] myData = m.getBody();
});
container.setQueueNames(queue.getName());
container.start();
```

Comment: Очередь я создаю и прослушиваю самую обычную. Создаю её не руками, а приложением (хотя даже если создать руками ничего не меняется). Есть ли возможность настроить эту библиотеку так, чтобы я мог сам решать, что делать с массивом байтов, который приходит? То есть условно сейчас мне на вход приходит `javax.jms.Message`, а я бы хотел `byte[]`

Comment: Во-первых, чтоб что-то настроить, нужно чтоб вы показали код, как вы сейчас читаете. А второе, вы, очевидно, невнимательно прочитали ответ. Еще раз, очередь самая обычная. Вопрос в том, как ее использовать. Если вы используете эту очередь клиентами JMS, то и сообщения в ней должны быть в формате jms (внутри сообщения может быть что угодно, но упаковано в jms). Если вы хотите получать сообщение из очереди и сами его интепретировать, то не создавайте jms listener-a. А читайте сообщения с помощью `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` из `spring-rabbit`. У меня впечатление, что вам не нужен JMS.

Comment: Добавил пример создания слушателя

Comment: Роман, есть ещё некоторая проблема: в моём приложении есть одновременная поддержка работы всех брокеров сообщений: IBM, ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ. Я полагаю, ваше решение применено только в RabbitMQ. Нужен какой то единый стандартизированный подход к созданию слушателей на обычные НЕ JMS сообщения.

Comment: Ну вопрос то вы задачи чуть о другом :) JMS это и есть стандартизированный способ работы в java. Приложение использует интерфейс jms , а провайдер сохраняет в своем формате. Для переключения между провайдерами прилоение менять ну нужно, нужно только изменить конфигурацию. Алтернативы - это если брокер поддреживает протоколы типа AMQP, STOMP, XMPP, MQTT. Тогда приложение вместо JSM api может использовать один из этих протоколов (с помощью библиотеки), для унифицированной комуникации с брокером. AMQP поддерживают все из названных вами.

Comment: А могли бы вы приложить пример как можно так сконфигурировать приложение? То есть сделать бины `ConnectionFactory` с `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "mq.manager", havingValue = "IBM_MQ")`, к примеру (и другими двумя). И таким образом по условию в `application.yaml` определять брокера. А потом пример создания слушателя на какую то очередь, чтобы создание было независимо от типа брокера (если так возможно)